# What is a bundle resource path in class loader? How do I access that path?

Tags: eclipse, websphere, resourcebundle

I have a web application deployed to Websphere and found that there are some conflicting jars. To find the path of the conflicting class I have added the below code

```
ClassLoader classLoader = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
URL resource = classLoader.getResource("org/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier.class");
System.out.println(resource);
```

When I check the IBM System.out log file I see the below path for resource. I am not sure what bundle resource path is. I would like to know how do I access the below location?

```
bundleresource://85.fwk734572965/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier.class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"bundleresource" URLs represent entries from the OSGi framework class loader.  The number maps to a bundle number in the OSGi configuration, which you can find by opening up the OSGi console (from the WAS_HOME/bin directory, `osgiConsole.sh|bat -server <servername>`) and running the "ss" command, which lists the bundles along with their state and numerical ID.

Assuming you're seeing a conflict at runtime through class loading (not actually pulling in these classes through getResource), I'll say with fairly strong certainty that you're picking up the conflicting classes from the JAX-RS prereq jar, `WAS_HOME/plugins/com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar`.  At the time it shipped, that jar made its copy of Apache HTTP visible to applications.  That visibility was removed in a later fixpack, if you're able to patch up your installation to the latest service level.

Note that even if you move to a newer fixpack with that fix, your testcase will probably still show the same thing - I don't think that `getResource()` is subject to the same filtering as `loadClass()`, so you might still be able to get at the .class file in that manner.  It might help with the issues you're seeing at runtime, though.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I also have the conflicting issue with httpclient jars. I have found the conflicting jars at WAS_HOME/plugins/com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar/META-INF/maven location. I realised that this jar versions are different from the versions of jars I added to project. This is not letting me execute my application in websphere. How do I resolve this conflicting issue for such jars?

Comment: The recommended way to override server-provided libraries with stuff in your application is to use an isolated shared library.  Basically, you take the specific jars that you KNOW you need your own version instead of the server's version, put them in some directory, create a shared library pointing to that directory, and select the "use an isolated class loader" checkbox.  That will load the classes in the library in preference to the classes in the server.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Do we have any other alternate way of overriding libraries? The reason being, though I make some change in the local console by adding shared library, I cannot make this change in dev and other environments as other apps will get affected. I would like to know, if I can make this happen just through the project code?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do it - the class loading settings are in the application's deployment settings, not in the application itself, and they can't be set in the app prior to deployment.  If you're comfortable with WSAdmin scripting, you could build a script that installs the app and immediately configures the library and class loader settings post-install, so it ends up effectively being one operation.